# Compress a list on recurring letters

Tags: python

While preparing for a test, I am solving tests from previous years.

Write the function `compress(lst)` that receives a non empty list of repetitive letters and returns a list of tuples, each tuple containing the letter and the number or subsequent repetitions. ( see example)

e.g.:

for:

```
['a','a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'a']
```

the function should return:

```
[('a', 2), ('b', 3), ('c', 1), ('a', 2)]
```

Here's my code:

```
def compress(lst):
    res = []
    i = 0
    for letter in lst:
        letter_count = 0
        while i < len(lst) and lst[i] == letter:
            letter_count += 1
            i +=1
        res.append((letter, letter_count))
    return res
```

My function returns:

```
[('a', 2), ('a', 0), ('b', 3), ('b', 0), ('b', 0), ('c', 1), ('a', 2), ('a', 0)]
```

I can see why it does that, but I cant see how to change *my* code to solve the problem.

Comment: `('b', 2)` ? sure?

Comment: The *simplest* fix seems straightforward: add `if letter_count:` before you append.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Corrected. Literally unbelievable, I took the answer from the solved tests they posted. This is a test from 2016, and amusingly the code they posted as their answer returns a wrong answer... Just my luck :)

Comment: @Tegernako, The correct way to indicate a problem is "solved" is to accept an answer (green tick on left). No need to indicative "solved" in the question title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Assuming you want to correct *your* code)

Save the `index` of the current analyzed letter and just sum to it how many times this letter repeats, so you skip already analyzed letters

```
def compress(lst):
    res = []
    i = 0
    ind = 0
    while ind < len(lst):
        letter_count = 0
        while i < len(lst) and lst[i] == lst[ind]:
            letter_count += 1
            i +=1
        res.append((lst[ind], letter_count))
        ind += letter_count
    return res

>>> compress(['a','a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'a'])
[('a', 2), ('b', 3), ('c', 1), ('a', 2)]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [**`groupby`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) from `itertools` module which perfectly fits here:

```
from itertools import groupby

lst = ['a','a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'a']

print([(k, len(list(v))) for k, v in groupby(lst)])
# [('a', 2), ('b', 3), ('c', 1), ('a', 2)]
```

Comment: Not really something you would use in a test while writing the code on paper, but thanks anyway for the comment.

Comment: No doubt itertools has insane functionality, but OP did ask how to modify _their_ code...

Comment: @Tegernako. I probably wouldn't write that on a test back when I was learning, but I totally would now.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Agreed, yet this is my first course in programming with zero exprience in the field before I started studying, and therefore those answers are acceptable. Also, we did not learn the standard library as this is an Introduction to CS course using Python, But still a great answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the `while` loop correctly counts occurrences, the `for` loop marches on inexorably, one character at a time. Since you're already incrementing the index correctly in the `while` loop, the simplest thing would be to get rid of either the `for` or `while` loop entirely. The only purpose to having multiple loops here is to attempt to avoid an `if`, and as you see, that doesn't really work.

```
res = []
prev = ''
for letter in lst:
    if prev == letter:
        letter_count += 1
    else:
        if prev:
            res.append((prev, letter_count))
        letter_count = 1
    prev = letter
```

This is similar to what you'd get from `itertools.groupby`:

```
[(k, len(list(g))) for k, g in groupby(lst)]
```

Answer (score 1):

`groupby` is the pythonic way. If you want to emulate that, you can do it with `O(1)` with only one loop, no indexes (not very pythonic) and a variable to store the previous letter:

```
def compress(lst):
    res = []
    previous_letter = None
    count = 0

    for letter in lst:
        if previous_letter is None:
            # first time
            count += 1
            previous_letter = letter
        elif previous_letter == letter:
            # same letter as before, count
            count += 1
        else:
            # different letter: store result, reset counter
            res.append((previous_letter,count))
            count = 1
            previous_letter = letter

     # last iteration doesn't append the last result, fix this
    res.append((previous_letter,count))
    return res
```

result:

```
[('a', 2), ('b', 3), ('c', 1), ('a', 2)]
```